# Unity3d Photon custom room property problem for making countdown timer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm trying to make countdown timer for adding my game match by using custom properties. But i'm stuck somewhere. Timer is working but it's not shows same time with another clients who join later. My script here:

```
public float Totaltime = 600;

void Update()
{
  Totaltime -= Time.deltaTime;
  StartCountDownTimer(Totaltime);
}

void StartCountDownTimer(float totalSeconds)
{
  Hashtable ht = new Hashtable() { { "startTime", totalSeconds } };
  PhotonNetwork.room.SetCustomProperties(ht);

  float updatedSecond = (float)PhotonNetwork.room.CustomProperties["startTime"];

  int minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(updatedSecond / 60f);
  int seconds = Mathf.RoundToInt(updatedSecond % 60f);

  string formatedSeconds = seconds.ToString();

  if (seconds == 60)
  {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes += 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue in the logic of code. You should only set the start time on the master client. Other clients read the start time and calculate the remaining time in the local client. After the countdown ends, the master client sends an RPC call to notify other clients to do next step.